# How to initialize spring-boot WebMvc? (ServletContext always null)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-web

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-web` to add an embedded webserver to an existing application.

Problem: the `servletContext` is always `null` during startup.

I'm running my application using `ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Config.class);`

If I exclude the `WebMvcAutoConfiguration` the ctx works as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Config implements ServletContextInitializer {
      @Override
      public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
          servletContext.getSessionCookieConfig().setName("yourCookieName");
      }
}
```

But as I need the AutoConfiguration, I remove the exclude. And in this case, the following error is thrown during startup because the `servletContext` is null.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.<init>(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.defaultServletHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:426)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f3d6343f.CGLIB$defaultServletHandlerMapping$34(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f3d6343f$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ee873d68.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f3d6343f.defaultServletHandlerMapping(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 18 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I had a statement in `application.properties`:

## spring.main.web_environment=false

Of course the webmvc cannot initialize while this statement exists.